# Why are the Minecraft subtitles saying I equip gear when I eat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My sound breaks every here and there, so I use the new Minecraft feature added in the release 1.9: Subtitles. I already learned to use them, but sometimes they surprise me by what they write, like "Enderman vwoops".

But when I eat it shows this:

[image: What the fu****ck?!?!]

It says something equipped some gear (armor) when I eat. I didn't manage to hear the sound while eating (if there is any). So, **is this a bug (does the game think I'm equipping some gear), or is this on purpose?**

Also I sometimes see "minecraft rolls". I'm playing on vanilla Minecraft version 1.10.2 and I didn't notice this in any older version.

Comment: How else would you describe the Enderman noise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are bugs, and it has been submitted to the Mojang Issue Tracker:

- ["Gear equipped"](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-97507) - When throwing a splash potion.
- ["Gear equipped"](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-101162) - Eating something, tested with many food items.
- ["Minecart Rolls"](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-91163) - Suggested that it happens when a chunk with a Minecart is rendered, even if the Minecart can't be seen.